# SAPUI5 Table: unbindRows & destroyColumns cause error: Cannot read property 'shouldRender' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using the `Table` object from the `SAPUI5's sap.ui.table` namespace:

> var oTableOverview = new sap.ui.table.Table();

On `rowSelectionChange`, when selecting one row I populate another table, let's call it `oTableDetail`, that is filled with some data.

When deselecting the row from the first table, I want to clear the content of the second, and for that I use:

> oTableDetail.destroyColumns();
>
> oTableDetail.unbindRows();

When deselecting the row I get the following error:

**TableRenderer.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shouldRender' of undefined**

I found the method `shouldRender` of the `sap.ui.table.Column` class, but I am not sure why would the cells be rerendered in this case.

I also noticed that if I use either `oTable.destroyColumns()`, or `oTable.unbindRows()` **separately**, the error does not appear.

I am using the "1.38.11" version of SAPUI5.

Can you please help me identify why this happens?

**EDIT 1**:  A possible *workaround* would be to use:

> oTableDetail.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({}));
>
> oTableDetail.destroyColumns();

Although I still don't know why the code mentioned before is not working.

**EDIT 2**: A behavior that I find a bit weird:

trying to add a setTimeout like this works (the error is not happening):

> oTable.destroyColumns();
>
> setTimeout(function(){  oTable.unbindRows();  }, 50);

but this other way it doesn't work (the error still appears) even if the delay is longer:

> oTable.unbindRows();
>
> setTimeout(function(){  oTable.destroyColumns();  }, 50);

Comment: Alina, try to use first oTable.unbindRows() and second oTable.destroyColumns().

Comment: Jaro, thank you for the suggestion! I tried it, but unfortunately the error still  appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oTableOverview = new sap.ui.table.Table();
//your model with new dynamic data
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(newData);

oTableDetail.setModel(oModel);
//use rerender method which tries to replace
//its DOM reference by re-rendering with new data.
oTableDetail.rerender();
```

You don't need to actually delete columns or unbind rows. 
[Rerender method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#rerender) will take care of new data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... What I need is not really to set another model to the table, but to empty it, or to unbind the rows. When I deselect the row from the upper table I don't need to see anything in the table below it.

Comment: set empty array in the data and rerender(), rest let the framework take care.

Answer (score 0):

So if you don't want to set a new model, then just try to clean oData of an existing model.

```
var oTable = this.byId("oTable")
//your model with new dynamic data
var oModel = oTable.getModel();

oModel.setData(null);
// then if its needed, use updateBindings method to refresh
oModel.updateBindings();
```